# What do you expect after a subscribing to a newsletter?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, newsletter

after user is subscribing to newsletter and so click the "register button" i can show a message where i alert the user that i have send an message to email... But i don't know how show this message:

1) overlay ? inside it i show the message and i alert the user that if close the overlay he goes to homepage... For me it isn't good idea overlay

2) open another page where there's the message? Ok is good but i have two problem: passa email data and time loading of page

3) when click the button the content of div (button, cta ecc ecc) is removed and i show only the new message. This is too easy but i don't know if good for UXD and i don't know if i should to remove also title (h1) of page

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: A newsletter subscription never happened to me in without it being an accident. The one thing I expect is a simple one click link to end the subscription.

Comment: @Traubenfuchs yes ok...there's a CTA to end the subscription, but is too important give to user a feedback and in this way the user can understand that the subscrioption is finish. But how ? new page with welcome message ? overlay or referesh of content with the new message ? Do you understand now where i want to tell you ? Thank a lot and sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, the number one thing a user expects after subscribing to something (be it a newsletter, service, etc) or after submitting data (be it a form, uploading documents, etc) is a confirmation that what they've just done was successful.

Now, how you do this may be restricted by your requirements (yours, your client's, the company you work for, etc), but the best option from a user's perspective is to just present them with the confirmation message.

If it was me I would opt for the current page to just refresh with the confirmation message and some suggested links to explore. If you require them to actually click on some sort of confirmation in their email, then the page would also explain this.

This approach is fast and responsive and does away with any gimmicks.

Comment: So for you is better the third option right ? I think that it is the fastest way...the overlay can creates positioning and graphics problems